# How to link client identity to userRole in OPC-UA

Tags: opc-ua

OPC-UA can restrict access to nodes via the userRole mechanism specified in OPC-UA Part 3, ch. 4.8.3:

> When a Client attempts to access a Node, the Server goes through the list of Roles granted to the Session and logically ORs the Permissions for the Role on the Node.

A session should map user identity (or the certificate of the client application) to a role. Thus, the server can grant or deny access to nodes.

> standard mapping rules can be used to determine which Roles a Session has access to and, consequently, the Permissions that are granted to the Session.

Now, the configuration schema of the server applications allows defining a `UserRoleDirectory` where I would *expect* files that somehow link a user (or client application certificate) to a role.
Unfortunately, the `UserRoleDirectory` appears to be undocumented.

So, the questions are:

- Will the OPC Foundation's .NET sample server indeed use files in `UserRoleDirectory` for said  purpose ?
- If so, what format take the files in said directory ?
- If not so, how to tie users or client instances to roles ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?